# pip requirements for relative packages

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, uv-package-installer

I have following structure

```bash
libs/lib_1/pyproject.toml
libs/lib_2/pyproject.toml -> uses lib_1
service/service_1/pyproject.toml -> uses lib_2
```

In `service_1/pyproject.toml`

I am using `lib_2` and imported it as

```ini
[project]
name = "service-2"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = [
    "lib_2@file:///${PROJECT_ROOT}/../../libs/lib_2",
]
```

In `lib2/pyproject.toml`

I am using `lib_1` and imported it as

```ini
[project]
name = "lib-2"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = [
    "lib_1@file:///${PROJECT_ROOT}/../lib_1",
]
```

When I am in directory `libs/lib_2` and try to install packages it works perfectly.

When I am in directory `service/service_1` and try to install it fails because it is trying to search lib_1 at `service/lib_1`.

How can I fix this ? Looking for fix without poetry.

Looks like its not natively supported in pip, can we do it using new uv (https://github.com/astral-sh/uv)

Comment: I do not think it is possible, or at least I very much doubt this is standard to use relative path dependencies. Where did you find this notation? As far as I know this is the standard specification: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#file-urls

Comment: @sinoroc regarding PROJECT_ROOT I referred from here stackoverflow.com/a/77181715/4659530 it did work for some part not fully

PROJECT_ROOT is supported in `pdm` and `uv` and setting `PROJECT_ROOT`

Comment: Thing is: it will very likely not work once it is built into a wheel, and for sure PyPI will not accept a wheel with path dependencies.

Comment: The local paths are suitable as requirements for your *build system*, while `lib_1` and `lib_2` should be used as package dependencies.